# Cron Expression: starting a job after completion of another job

Tags: cron, expression

I have to perform 2 jobs - A and B. Job 'A' is to be prformed at 9:00 am of every weekday. I dont know the duration for job 'A' though, duration may vary.

Also I want to perform job 'B' after 3mins of completion of job 'A'.

Can anyone suggest the cron expression for this please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to run the second job three minutes after the first job completes, let's say you have Job A which involves calling /home/user/job_a.sh and then once that completes, you want to run /home/user/job_b.sh. Instead of trying to set up two different Cron jobs, you could just make a separate script, say job_c.sh. And all job_c.sh does is run Job A, wait three minutes and then run Job B.

Basically, rather than calling two Cron Jobs and trying to sort out timing for both of them, you can just establish one Cron Job which runs both jobs.

On the other hand, if you want to run the second job three minutes after the first one *starts* then you might as well create two Cron Jobs with three minutes between them which would look something like this:

```
00 9 * * 1-5 /home/user/job_a.sh
03 9 * * 1-5 /home/user/job_b.sh
```